# Flutter filter push notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to successfully send from Firebase push notifications and receive them on mobile. I can do everything (so far) using the official [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package.

---

In my Flutter app there's a variable called `bool isAdmin` which can be true or false, it depends. I need to make it so that some notifications are seen only by people that are actually admins.

In other words, certain push notifications can be seen only if `isAdmin = true`. How can I do this?

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I am thinking to add a flag in the body payload of the push notification called `adminPush` which can be true or false. But then, how can I read this field and prevent the notification to appear?

Comment: What if you can think about the user base filtration in server side itself and push message based on user base grouping?

Comment: may I have a reference to this? I can basically make an "user pool" on Firebase and dispatch messages only to those people?

Comment: I suggest creating an 'adminUser' FCM topic that only admin users are subscribed to. Then use this topic to 'broadcast' only to admin users. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging for various suggestions. Andrey Ilyunin answer is also a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) the `notification` block of the push notification gets displayed by the push notifications SDK itself if the app is backgrounded, so one way to fix this is sending only `data` block, omitting `notification` block altogether for this particular push notification type, and displaying a local notification if `isAdmin = true`.